# Current Voltage characteristic of Josephson Junction

Tags: electric-current, voltage, josephson-junction

I'm having trouble understanding what the current voltage characteristic of a Josephson Junction looks like.

When we first looked at the voltage state of a Josephson Junction we got the following graph:
[image]

After that we analysed the RCSJ model and we got this graph:
[image]

Where a) corresponds to an overdamped Junction and b) to an underdamped one.

My question is: when do we get a graph like the first one as opposed to the second one?

Answer (score 0):

The first graph appears to correspond to an un-shunted junction. (a) would be the IV curve when driven with an ideal current source, and (b) would be the curve when driven with an ideal voltage source. The slope of the resistive branch, $I>I_c$ is the normal-state conductance of the junction.